# ls and find command excluding a certain directory

Tags: grep, find, ls

I want to do this:

```
ls -altrhS 'find / -type d \( ! -name tmp -prune \) -size +10000k 2> /dev/null -print' | egrep -v 'ibd|MYD|MYI'
```

So I want to list, in that format, files of a specific size excluding the tmp directory. All that I've read says that should do it, but it does not work, I keep getting the temp directory stuff as well.

Comment: Are you getting an entry for `/tmp` by itself? I suspect that what happens is that directories under `/tmp` will be listed, but any directory whose name is `/tmp` will not be. If you want to exclude anything uder and including `/tmp`, then this command would probably do it `find / -type d -size +10000k 2> /dev/null -print' | egrep -v 'ibd|MYD|MYI|/tmp'`. I'm not sure what the `ls -altrhS` is doing. Is it meant to be there?

Comment: I just get an empty prompt like it is asking for more info with what you gave me..

Comment: Oops. An erroneous quote mark. Try `find / -type d -size +10000k 2> /dev/null -print | egrep -v 'ibd|MYD|MYI|/tmp'` although I believe that the `-print` is entirely optional as it is the default value anyway.

Comment: @Warwick This outputs nothing when I know there are files on there that meet the requirement. hm I should of seen the mistake, I was just in a hurry. This is a little side project I'm doing at work.  Basically I'm looking for files that are a certain size, but I don't want to see the ones that are in temp folder as they are not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
find / -not -path "*/tmp/*" -size +10000k -ls 2> /dev/null | \
sort -n -k7 | egrep -v 'ibd|MYD|MYI'
```

**Explanation:**

- `find / -not -path "*/tmp/*" -size +10000k -ls`: find everthing whose path does not start with `/tmp/` with the size greater than 10000k and prints the output in `find`'s own `ls -dils` format.
- `sort -n -k7`: As your statement in the question `ls -altrhS`, I assume you want the output to be sorted by the filesize ascending. In the `ls -dils` output of `find` the 7th field is the filesize
- `egrep -v 'ibd|MYD|MYI'` and your own `egrep` part to filter away those strings

**Edit:**

If you want the human readable file size format of `ls` use this command:

```
find / -type f -not -path "*/tmp/*" -size +10000k -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -n -k1 | cut -d' ' -f2- | xargs -L 1 ls -lh
```

Comment: Is there away to show filesize in gb/mb next to it instead of kb?  And thank you this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @KirsKringle see my edit

Comment: I get "sort: invalid option --'h'  I tried running with -n, but it included the tmp folder again.

Comment: your sort does not support the -h flag, let me think a moment...

Comment: Thank you for all of your help your genius.  Seriously.  Haha if you cannot think something you've more than helped. I'm just thinking to give this to colleagues and it would help them see the info easier.  If not no big deal.  Thanks again.

Comment: @KirsKringle try the command in the edit again. Should work now =)

Comment: This worked perfect! you da' man